# WCF rest service with XML or JSon request gives 400 bad request

Tags: wcf, rest

I have tried all the options I can think of from my research on the net, but perhaps I am missing something obvious that I just can't see.

This is my interface definition

```
[ScriptService] 
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{

    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
    [OperationContract]
    //[FaultContract(typeof(MycustomFault))]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetData/{Request}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    string GetData(string Request);

}
```

This is my service class

```
[ScriptService]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class Service : IService
{
    public string GetData(string Request)
    {
      //break point at code here
    }
}
```

This is the service config

```
   <system.serviceModel>
   <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="webHttpBinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior >
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

I test this service by calling the url like so: `http://localhost:4196/Service.svc/GetData/<myxml>somedata</myxml>`
I get a 400 bad request when I try to send any xml content via the browser using the url above. It doesn't even hit the beakpoint. However if I send plain text it goes thru. For eg: if I call the url like this `http://localhost:4196/Service.svc/GetData/someplaintextdatahere` it works and I hit the breakpoint.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try enabling tracing on the server to see why the request is considered to be a bad one.

Comment: thanks Carlos.. Im using casini right now. I havnt deployed it on IIS .. or did you mean in my service?

Comment: In the service itself (via web.config)

Comment: when I opened the error log in Service Trace Viewer I got a message "There is an unclosed literal string" .. then it proceeded to show me the logs ..but I dont know what to make of it.

Answer (score 1):

you send wrond symbols by url `<>` you must encode it

`http://localhost:4196/Service.svc/GetData/&lt;myxml&gt;somedata&lt;/myxml&gt;`

Comment: so the service is correct from all perspectives? and this is a client only issue?

Comment: Encoding angle brackets in URLs should not be done by using XML escapes (i.e., `&lt;` or `&gt;`). Encoding in URLs should be done using URL encoding: %60 for `<` and %62 for `>`.

Comment: I will try encoding the parameter. Legion: this is a question for you. Why not send XML as a parameter? Suppose i change from xml input to json..will the encoding still work?. I suppose it should.

Comment: because you can send xml as class in context body, and send only simple param as url segment

Comment: this service will be consumed by a javascript client.. Im not sure how to do that.

Comment: carlos.. I tried encoding with .net using Htmlutility.UrlEncode and got a string with %3c for < and %3e for > .. and it continued to give me bad request..

Comment: with using %60 for < and %62 for >, after just about 70 chars I get an error saying endpoint not found... if I reduce the size of the Urlencoded string to about 36 chars then the break-point gets hit again.